# Remove rows/columns of Org table before passing to a Babel block

Tags: org-babel, org-table

Is there a simple way to remove specific rows/columns of an Org table when passing them to a Babel block?

For example, I'd like to process the data in the table below using Matlab. The column headers are automatically removed, but I also need the row 'headers' on the left to organize the data before processing.

```
#+name: test-table
|            | colheader1 | colheader2 |
|------------+------------+------------|
| rowheader1 |          2 |          8 |
| rowheader2 |          4 |         10 |
| rowheader3 |          6 |         12 |

#+begin_src matlab :var x=test-table
a = x;
ans = a
#+end_src
```

If the leftmost column with 'headers' were removed, Matlab would receive the matrix `[2 8;4 10;6 12]`, and the result would be:

```
#+results:
| 2 |  8 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 6 | 12 |
```

However, I get no result, presumably since Matlab doesn't know how to process a matrix with text and numerics without some type of cell classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have `matlab` - here's a python version:

```el
#+name: test-table
|            | colheader1 | colheader2 |
|------------+------------+------------|
| rowheader1 |          2 |          8 |
| rowheader2 |          4 |         10 |
| rowheader3 |          6 |         12 |

#+begin_src python :results value :var x=test-table[,1:2]
    return x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 2 |  8 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 6 | 12 |
```

See [Environment of a Code Block](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Environment-of-a-Code-Block).

Comment: Yes, the [,1:2] syntax worked for Matlab as well.